# Nvidia Video Screen Tearing (proprietary driver)

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, video

I am getting near-constant **screen tearing** when watching videos on my Ideapad Y400, with **Nvidia GT 650M** graphics (not the SLI model).

I am using the proprietary **337 drivers** from xorg-edgers, but the same effects happened with 304 (and 313, I think).  I use **Ubuntu 13.10 and i3wm**.

Enabling and disabling OpenGL Vsync in nvidia-settings makes no difference.  I don't see any other relevant options.  I have tried both VLC and the built-in "videos" application, and both suffer screen tearing.  The tearing does not occur when I run Windows.  I have not tried another monitor, as I can't get hdmi-out to work (I haven't tried VGA).

Do y'all have any ideas?

Note:  As I have swapped among various versions of Noveau and proprietary drivers, the tty's have changed appearance a bit.  At the moment, they appear to be correct except for two vertical lines of slight blurriness -- 2px off from the right horizontal resolution?

Comment: Just my two cents: From what I've read Vsync doesn't *actually* exist in X11. Therefore, Vsync/sync to vblank doesn't really do anything. I have the same issue sometimes, but it's most noticeable when I'm running on my OpenBox desktop that I use for certain tasks. This happens even with a compositor no matter which one I've tried using. So, it's probably a problem we'll have to deal with until NVIDIA finds a way to fix it or X11 adds true vsync support -- if ever.